# On the Universality of the Riemann zeta-function

Tags: riemann-zeta-function, cv.complex-variables

Hi,

I have a question regarding the universality property of the Riemann zeta-function. I am no expert on this, so I'd be glad for any relevant reference.

First, recall Voronin's remarkable theorem on the Universality of the Riemann zeta-function :

Let $K$ be a compact subset with connected complement lying in the strip $\{1/2 < \operatorname{Re}(z)<1\}$, and let $f : K \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be continuous, holomorphic on the interior of $K$, and zero-free on $K$. Then for each $\epsilon>0$, there exists $t>0$ such that
$$\max_{z \in K} |\zeta(z+it)-f(z)|<\epsilon.$$
Even more : the lower density of the set of such $t$'s is positive..!

Note that of course, the hypothesis that the complement of $K$ is connected is essential in the above theorem.

My question is the following :

**Is there some sort of (modified) zeta-function universality-like result for compact sets $K$ with *disconnected* complements? For example, if $\mathbb{C}_\infty \setminus K$ has a finite number of components?**

**EDIT**

Of course I know that a sequence of the form $f_n(z):=\zeta(z+it_n)$ won't work in the case when the complement of $K$ is disconnected (such a sequence cannot approximate uniformly say $1/z$ on an annulus centered at $0$). I'm asking wether there is **some** sequence of functions, involving the Riemann zeta-function, that could work in this case, and generalize Voronin's Theorem. Note that such functions will necessarily have poles in each component of the complement of $K$.

**2nd EDIT**

Let me explain what I was looking for here. Basically, I'd like to know if there exists a result of the following form :

Let $K$ be a compact subset **whose complement has finitely many components** lying in the strip $\{1/2 < \operatorname{Re}(z)<1\}$, and let $f : K \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be continuous, holomorphic on the interior of $K$, and zero-free on $K$. Then for each $\epsilon>0$, there exists...

*Here insert some uniform approximation of $f$ on $K$ by a function involving the Riemann zeta-function*

Furthermore, in the case when $K$ has **connected** complement, I would like the above result to reduce to Voronin's Theorem.

In summary, I want to know if there exists a generalization of Voronin's Theorem to compact sets whose complement have finitely many components.

Thank you,
Malik

Comment: There is an approximation theorem of Arakelian, which is essentially an iff-statement. So there is no extension of Mergelyan in the sense you search for. the domain has to be contractible in any case.

Comment: contractible to a point, I meant to say.

Comment: @MarcPalm : There is definitely a confusion here. I am talking about Mergelyan's theorem on uniform approximation by *rational functions*. Of course, uniform approximation by *polynomials* is only possible in the "connected complement" case! I'll edit the question for more clarity.

Comment: Is this question purely out of curiosity, or do have something concrete in mind?

Comment: You misunderstood me. Observe the difference of K and K0 in my second post.

Comment: What do you mean by *reduce to  Voronin*?

Comment: I mean, the result I'm looking for should contain Voronin's Universality Theorem as a particular case (the case when the complement of $K$ is connected).

Comment: I have chosen to delete my other answer because there was a mistake in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a cheaper alternative depending on what you mean by a modification. Consider $L(z)$ any Dirichlet L function different from $\zeta$.

> **Joint universality theorem**: 
>   Let $K$ be a compact set in the right half of the critical stripe $1/2< \Re s<1$ with connected complement. For any two functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ holomorphic in the interior of $K$ (vanishing or not) and every $\epsilon>0$, we have that the limit
>   $$ \inf\lim\limits_{T \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{T} \lambda \{ t \leq T: \sup |f_1(z) - \log \zeta(z +i t)| +  \sup |f_2(z) - \log L(z +i t)| < \epsilon\} $$
>   is positive for $\lambda$ being the Lebesgue measure.

From this, we can deduce:

> **Corollary**: Let $K_0$ be a compact set in the right half of the critical stripe $1/2< \Re s<1$.
>   Let $f$ be a continuous function on $K_0$, which is holomorphic on an open set containing $K_0$. For every $\epsilon_0>0$, we have that the limit
>   $$ \inf\lim\limits_{T \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{T} \lambda \Big\{ t \leq T: \sup\limits_{z \in K_0} \left| f(z) - \frac{\log \zeta(z +i t)}{\log L(z+ it)}\right| < \epsilon_0\Big\} $$
>   is positive for $\lambda$ being the Lebesgue measure.

*Proof*:
By Runge's theorem, it is sufficient to approximate rational functions, whose poles lie outside of $K_0$. Let $p(z)$ and $q(z)$ be polynomials such that $q$ does not vanish on $K_0$. Consider $\epsilon_0>0$ sufficiently small (to be made precise as we go on).

Let $K :=\mathbb{C}-O$, where $O$ is the unbounded, connected component of $\mathbb{C}-K_0$. Consider $\epsilon>0$ sufficiently small, then use the joint universality theorem for $f_1(z)=p(z)$ and $f_2(z) =q(z)$.

We want to show that 
$$\sup | f_1/f_2(z) - \frac{\log \zeta}{\log L}(z+i t) |< \epsilon_0.$$

We estimate the left-hand side:
$$ \leq \sup | f_1/f_2(z) - \frac{\log \zeta(z+it)}{f_2(z)} | +  \sup | \frac{\log \zeta(z+it)}{f_2(z)} - \frac{\log \zeta}{\log L}(z+i t)|.$$

The first summand is easy to estimate:
$$\sup | f_1/f_2(z) - \frac{\log \zeta(z+it)}{f_2(z)} | \leq \sup_{z \in K_0} \left| f_2(z)^{-1} \right| \epsilon.$$
The second one is a little bit harder:
$$  \sup \Big| \frac{\log \zeta(z+it)}{f_2(z)} - \frac{\log \zeta}{\log L}(z+i t)\Big| \leq $$
$$ \sup \Big|  \frac{\log \zeta(z+i t)}{f_2(z)\log L(z+i t)} \Big|  \sup |  \log L(z+i t) -f_2(z) | <  \sup \Big|  \frac{\log \zeta(z+i t)}{f_2(z) \log L(z+i t)} \Big|  \epsilon,$$
because we have to estimate
$$ \sup |  \frac{\log \zeta}{\log L}(z+i t) | $$
uniformly in $t$.

This is indeed possible, we have that
$$\sup | f_2(z) |  - \sup | \log  L(z + i t) | < \epsilon$$
and
$$ \sup | \log  \zeta(z + i t) | - \sup | f_1(z) |  < \epsilon$$
by the reversed triangle inequality.
So for $\epsilon \leq \sup | f_2(z) |/2$ and $\epsilon \leq \sup | f_1(z) |$ , we have that
$$  \sup | \log  L(z + i t) | > \sup | f_2(z) |/2$$
and
$$ \sup | \log  \zeta(z + i t) | < 2 \sup | f_1(z) | .$$
So 
$$\epsilon_0 := \max\{ \frac{1}{2} \sup |f_2^{-1}| \epsilon, \frac{1}{2} 4* \sup |f_1f_2^{-2}| \epsilon \}$$
will do.

This finishes the proof of the corollary assuming the Joint universality theorem.

Comment: This joint universality result is interesting, but what I'm looking for is really a result for compact sets with *disconnected* complements. Also, just to clarify : I don't want to remove the non-vanishing assumption. I'm fine with it!

Comment: See my new edit. I hope it clarifies what I'm looking for here.

Comment: I think I provide exactly what you want. K_0 is assumed to have holes at the zeros of f_2. Of course K is not K_0.

Comment: Oh I see, indeed I misread $K_0$ for $K$, sorry about that! But I don't understand why you work with $\log$..?

Comment: it doesn't work without log in that way. sorry if that is not in the sense you wanted it to be.

Comment: @MarcPalm : Yes, indeed, I see now why we need $\log$. But still, it is a good idea to work with joint universality. Thanks, +1 !

Answer (score 2):

No, it cannot be true. Suppose the theorem holds for an appropriate translation of the annulus $K:=\{1/2 \leq z \leq 1\}$ and the function $f(z)=1/z$. Then there is a sequence $f_n$ of holomorphic functions on the closed unit disc, continuous on the boundary, such that $f_n (z) \to 1/z$ uniformly in $K$ (because $\zeta$ does not have a pole away from $1$). By the maximum principle, the convergence extends to the whole unit disc, contradicting the identity theorem, because $f$ is not holomorphic on the disc.

Comment: Yes, of course, the theorem, as stated, does not hold if you remove the hypothesis that the complement of $K$ is connected. I'm asking if there exists a (different) universality-like result that would work for compact sets with disconnected complements. Sorry if that wasn't clear, I'll edit the question... 

Comment: @JohannesEbert : Do you think the question is clear now?

Comment: Yes, now the question is clear, I was misunderstanding it.

Comment: @MarcPalm : See my comment to the question... There is a confusion here.